# Inline Editing, remove input

Tags: jquery, html-table, editing

I have the following code to make Inline Editing of an table row possible:

```
$('.edit_td').click(function() {
    var td_value = $(this).text();  
    $(this).html('<input type="text" value="' + $(this).html() + '">');
});
```

This works fine, but when I switch to another row, I want the first row to transform back from an input-field, to the original td. And ofcourse, the row that I click on, should transform to an input-field with the td-text inside of it.

I've tried the `.blur()`, but when I use that, the td is not transformed to an input-field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place a class on the cell being edited, which you can then retrieve on the next click of `edit` and set the text value back again. Something like this:

```
$('.edit_td').click(function() {
    resetEditedCells(); 
    $(this).addClass('active').html('<input type="text" value="' + $(this).html() + '">');
});

function resetEditedCells() {
    $('.edit_td.active').removeClass('active').html(function() {
        return $(this).find('input').val();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain what the resetEditedCells do? I can't understand how it resets the cells.

Comment: @user500468 it sets the html to input value.

Comment: Ok. How can I transform the input field back to the td, when I click outside the table/td? When I click anywere on the site, except on the table td, I want the input field to transform back to td.

Comment: How can I remove the input fields when I click outside the element?

Comment: @user500468 It would be best to start a new question for that.\

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/9HL74/)**

```
$('.edit_td').click(function() {
    var td_value = $(this).text(); 
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    $(this).remove();
    parent.html('<input type="text" value="' + $(this).html() + '">');

    $('input').on('focusout blur',function(){

        $(this).parent().append('<td>'+$(this).val()+'</td>');
        $(this).remove();
    });
})
```